# File/Folder browser dialog appears twice

Tags: c#, dialog, visual-studio-2013

I am making a program with `C#` using Visual Studio 2013 Express that launches an application (in portable mode), and makes a virtual drive out of a folder (using the `subst` command or a C# equivalent)
At the moment it's meant for the popular media center XBMC, but it can eventually also be used for other programs

On the first screen the user can select the path to the XBMC.exe file and the directory containing the media collection.
[image: Select exe and media folder screen]

However, while testing, both dialogs appear twice: once after clicking on the "Browse" button, and once again after clicking on either the "OK" or "Cancel" button (in the dialog). So I have to click "OK" twice every time before the selected path/file is inserted into the textbox.
I have no idea why that's happening, and I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to programming myself...

`XBMCPortableLauncher.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XBMCAttempt1
{
    public partial class XBMCPortableLauncher : Form
    {
        public XBMCPortableLauncher()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSelectMediaFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Opens "Browse for media folder" dialog
            fBDBrowseMediaFolder.ShowDialog();
            if (fBDBrowseMediaFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Deletes any existing text in the textbox
                tbMediaFolder.Clear();
                // Inserts the selected path into the text box if user selects "OK"
                tbMediaFolder.Text = fBDBrowseMediaFolder.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void btnSelectXBMCexe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Opens the "Select XBMC.exe" dialog
            oFDBrowseXBMCexe.ShowDialog();
            if (oFDBrowseXBMCexe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Deletes any existing text in the textbox
                tbXBMCexe.Clear();
                // Inserts the selected file into the text box if user selects "OK"
                tbXBMCexe.Text = oFDBrowseXBMCexe.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and what I have to do to fix the problem?
*(if you need more information, just ask)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you're calling `ShowDIalog` twice. Can't be that easy:

```
fBDBrowseMediaFolder.ShowDialog();
if (fBDBrowseMediaFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

Remove the first call.

`ShowDialog` is blocking and in fact it does show your dialog and returns a `DialogResult`. So, keep only the second call where you actually use the result. And do that for both dialogs (`fBDBrowseMediaFolder` and `oFDBrowseXBMCexe`).

Comment: I would never have figured that out myself... Thanks for the help! (can I also keep both, but replace the second `showDialog()` with `DialogResult`?)

Comment: @nidunc: No, you cannot keep both because having both results in the dialog being displayed **twice**. So, keep only the second one.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted by my own stupidness... Well, I understand now, and won't make the same mistake again.